# Issues implementing simple 'toggle' / (show/hide) on div, on mouseclick, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a div class element toggle/ or show hide an  set of id elements upon mouse click. So on click on the 'result_location id' I'm trying to display all the divs  under result_menu class beneath it.

Am I going the right way about this? Hope you can help!  Here's my HTML and JS code:

HTML:

```
<div id="result_location">
     <h3>MainText Here</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="result_menu">
            <div id="a_column">
                <h4>text</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="b_column">
                <h4>text</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="c_column">
                <h4>text</h4>
             </div>

            <div id="d_column">
                <h4>text</h4>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result_location').click(function() {
            $('.result_menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What issues are you having?

Comment: Do you have multiple of those with id duplication?

Comment: working fine, check this http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/5TBzk/

Comment: For some reason that code, isn't working on my local file!  but is the same as yours, just with styles attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be working fine for me, I threw up a quick html page without a problem.  Only thing I can think of is that you must load jquery before the JS that you mentioned. Other than that it should be working!

Comment: Strange! Code looks the same, this is the result I get http://postimg.org/image/r6sbjgokf/  Where all the result_menu items are already displaying, and theres no response to any 'click' actions on screen

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console? Using Chrome(technically other browsers too, but I recommend chrome), You can right click anywhere on the page, click "Inspect Element" then click on "Console" at the top, are there any errors there? and if so, what are they?

Comment: As Raunak Kathuria added above, here is a jsfiddle, slightly modified to be more like your image, that is functioning: http://jsfiddle.net/f3JXr/

Comment: I am receiving one error, "Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/Duncan/Desktop/GA/Project/js/index.js"   but it is being linked at the end of the html doc

Comment: how is it being linked? based on that it appears you may have linked it incorrectly, is it being linked like this? (assuming your html file is in the "Project" directory:

<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: "<script src="js/index.js"></script>"  (after the footer, but before closing body and html tags)

Comment: after adding "type=text/javascript" I get this error in the console - " GET file:///C:/Users/Duncan/Desktop/GA/Project/js/index.js  "

Comment: index.js is in the same directory as index.html, but style.css is in a separate folder, if that helps

Comment: I'm such a douche, it was my lousy file directory placement - sorry guys

Comment: Haha it's all good, anyone who claims they've never made that kind of mistake has either never done any dev or they're lying!